# How to echo special characters like %, <cfile> in Vim?

Tags: vim

Say I wanna see what directory I am in, I type

```
:echo .
```

and get the error message:

```
E15:Invalid expression .
```

How can I echo out those special characters like `%`, `.`, `<cfile>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a dedicated command to print the current directory path:

```
:pwd
```

(See `:help :pwd` and the whole “The current directory” section in the
help: `:help current-directory`.)

To quickly find out what paths Vim command-line specials are expanded
to, use

```
:echo expand('%:p:h')
```

or, shorter,

```
:!echo %:p:h
```

The former command is based on the `expand()` function that expands
wildcards and special keywords in a given argument (see `:help expand`).
The latter command takes advantage of the fact that wildcards are
expanded before running an external command (see `:help cmdline-special`).

Comment: Thanks! It works when I type `echo expand("%")` but I get a `.` when I type `:echo expand('%:h:p')`. What do :h and :p mean?

Comment: @TomCaps:  I've mistyped the modifiers, thus reversing their order.  (Thanks for noticing that!)  The `:p` one, that should be applied first, expands the value of the preceding special variable to its full path.  The `:h` modifier, applied after that, removes the last path component, which is the file name in case of the `%` special.  This way, `%:p:h` denotes the full path to the directory containing the current file.  For the full list of special variables and their modifiers, see `:help expand()` and `:help cmdline-special`.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `expand()`

For example

```
:echo expand("%:h")
```

prints the actual directory (of the currenct buffer).

See also `:help expand`

If you want to inquire about the *current-directory* (which is buffer independant), you should just du a `:pwd`. (See `:help current-directory`)

(Edit: changed from `:cd` to `:pwd` as per comment of ib).

Comment: `:cd` prints the current directory name only on non-Unix systems.  On Unix systems it changes the current directory to the home one!  To print the current directory path use `:pwd`.

Comment: Thanks @ib. I have changed the answer accordingly.